# How to list Resources utilizing a IAM role in AWS and Best way to replace the roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How to list Resources utilizing an IAM role in AWS and the Best way to replace the roles. we are planning to replace the existing roles with new roles and we want to analyse what is the best way to replace the roles in Existing resources

Comment: What have you tried and what specific issues are you having? Are you having trouble listing resources with an IAM Role? What specific problem are you experiencing? And what do you mean by "replace the roles" -- replace them with what? Please Edit your question to add a lot more detail about what you are wanting to do (preferably with examples), what you have tried and what problems you are facing.

Comment: we are facing issues in identifying individual resources assuming a particular role. we had multiple projects where we have trusted roles that span across multiple accounts and realized that it can compromise other projects too if any single project gets compramised. so we decided to have a role confined to a single project. so it arose the need for replacement of current roles.

Comment: so we need the list of resources that are assuming this role but from IAM dashboard we are only getting the services assuming this role, not the individual resources.

Comment: Have you examined your AWS CloudTrail logs, looking for `AssumeRole` events?